# In Google BigQuery; how do I query a session's browser?

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google Analytics interface it's possible to find browser as an dimension, how to I select the same dimension through BigQuery?

Comment: universal analytics or ga4?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the number of users who utilized each browser in the last month with this query. Customize it according to your preferences.

```
SELECT
  browser,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS total_users
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      device.web_info.browser AS browser,
      user_pseudo_id
    FROM
      `project.dataset.events_*`
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE(
        '%Y%m%d',
        DATE_SUB(
          DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH),
          INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        )
      ) AND FORMAT_DATE(
        '%Y%m%d',
        DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
      )
    GROUP BY
      browser,
      user_pseudo_id
  )
GROUP BY
  browser
```